# ComboBox Binding to XML in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I know this question has been asked to death, but I have tried lots of the suggested answers I have found and the Combo Box is still not populating when I start the WPF in VS2013.  Here it goes.  I have an XML document called People.xml that is formatted like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<People>
  <Person>
    <personName>John Doe</personName>
    <personEmail>someone@yahoo.com</personEmail>
    <personReports>List of reports they get go here.</personReports>
</Person>
```

In App.xml portion of the application I have this as a resource:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="People" Source="\DataSources\People.xml" XPath="People" IsInitialLoadEnabled="True" />
```

Then, in the XAML for the combo box, I have it listed as this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="employeeNameBox" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource People}, XPath=./Person/personName}">
```

What I am trying to get at is populate the combo box with all of the personName elements in the XML doc.

Again, I have tried several different ways to try and get this to load, and the combo box always comes up empty.  I am relatively new to the data binding structures and WPF's in general, so any help I could get would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, simpliest way is `XmlSerializer`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string personName;
    public string personEmail;
    public string personReports;
}

public class People
{
    [XmlElement("Person")]
    public List<Person> Persons;
}
```

Load data:

```
var people = (People)new XmlSerializer(typeof(People)).Deserialize(stream);
employeeNameBox.ItemsSource = people.Persons;
```

ComboBox code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="employeeNameBox" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="personName">
```

Comment: I was hoping to do the binding in the WPF, but I will give this a shot

Comment: Hm, where do you store your xml file? Tried your code, it works. File attached to project.

Comment: I have a DataSource folder inside the project where the XML is

Comment: May be your file has wrong `BuildAction` property value. It should be set to `Resource`.