# wpf unable to bind combobox to XML file

Tags: xml, wpf, combobox

I'm new to WPF and am trying to bind an XML file to a combobox control.  Here is my XML, which I have added into my project with a name of AvailableTestsXMLFile2.xml...

```
<AvailableTests>
  <Test name="high voltage" testNumber="1" />
  <Test name="low voltage" testNumber="2" />
  <Test name="new test" testNumber="3" />
  <Test name="old test" testNumber="4" />
</AvailableTests>
```

Here is my XAML...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTester.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTester"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="AvailableTests" Source="AvailableTestsXMLFile2.xml" XPath="AvailableTests"/>   
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MaxWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="C:\Users\StarkS02\Pictures\abbott-logo.jpg" Height="42" Width="42"/>
        </Grid>

        <Border Background="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10" Margin="10" Width="450" Height="55">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>Configuration Section</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </Border>
        <Border Background="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10"  Margin="10">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>Select Test</TextBlock>
                <ComboBox x:Name="employeeNameBox" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AvailableTests}, XPath=./Test/name}">
            </ComboBox>                    
                <CheckBox Name="ChkRepeatTilFailure" Foreground="White" Content="Repeat Test Until Failure" Margin="5 5 5 5"/>
                <Button Content="Submit Test" Margin="4 4 4 4" Width="65"/>

            </StackPanel>

        </Border>
        <Border Background="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10" Margin="10" Height="65">

            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>Test Response Section</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="Test 3 Successful!" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When it runs there aren't any complier errors, but I don't end up with any values in my combobox.  Any ideas?

Comment: Added XPath to the XMLDataProvider and a source to the combobox binding but get error Inner Exception 1: Exception: Cannot find resource named 'AvailableTests'. Resource names are case sensitive. (this is on the line of the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

There was no source defined in itemsource binding of ComboBox . Correct that.

[ComboBox Binding to XML in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790405/combobox-binding-to-xml-in-wpf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Ok, I added a source but still get an error.  Here is my statement dealing with the binding...<ComboBox x:Name="employeeNameBox" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AvailableTests}, XPath=./Test/name}">
                </ComboBox>   //this errors Inner Exception 1:
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'AvailableTests'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Comment: The x:key you have is xmlData rather than availabletests.

Comment: Changed the x:key to AvailableTests, but still no data in my combobox.  The error about not finding the resource no longer happens.  I'm guessing I have an issue with my combobox ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0):

Your itemssource binding is wrong.
You need to use your xml as the source.
Carefully compare what you have to this:.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-xml-data-using-an-xmldataprovider-and-xpath-queries

Comment: I added an itemsource but still get an error.  It can't find AvalableTests from my XML and give me this error...Inner Exception 1:
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'AvailableTests'. Resource names are case sensitive.